# css not working in cffile write

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I have a report which is enclosed in a cfsavecontent tag.

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "testcust">
```

When I use

```
<cfoutput> #testcust# </cfoutput>
```

the report renders correctly.  When I use cffile to save it to disk I lose the css formatting:

```
<cffile action = "write"
file   = "/var/www/reports/testcust.cfm"
output = "#testcust#">
```

I can run testcust.cfm and it produces the report.  All in-line styling is preserved.  But formatting from the style sheet is not there.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you need to write the css file to your .cfm file

Comment: This worked so far as it goes.  I included a <style tag within my <cfsavecontent tag, and wrote out the style I am testing. It was rendered in testcust.cfm, so this is a good start.  Do you know of any way to get the entire style sheet in there in a dynamic way (i.e. if I change the style sheet that would be reflected in the report).  If that can't be done, every time I change something in the style sheet I would have to make a manual change to the report.

Comment: Oh, never mind -- I added in a <link rel (etc) and it was fine.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the html special characters. e.g `<` for `&lt;` and `>` for `&gt;`

So replace them before writing to file.

Comment: *e.g `<` for `&lt;`* Not sure what you mean. That is the opposite of escaping. If you meant the reverse, that would cause tags to be displayed rather than evaluated.

Comment: yes the reverse. I meant replace `<` with `&lt;` and replace `>` with  `&gt;` . This would allow the tags symbol to remain in the output file instead of being evaluated.